# How to pass vectors of serialized class via boost MPI?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, vector, mpi

I am totally new to parallel computing and Boost library. But in my current project, I need send/recv a vector contain serialized class objects and the size will be decided in run time. After read the boost::mpi and boost::serialization document, I find below code while search in Google and compiled it using vs2008 with no error.

```
#include <boost/mpi.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
namespace mpi = boost::mpi;

class gps_position
{
private:
 friend class boost::serialization::access;

template<class Archive>
 void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
 {
   ar & degrees;
   ar & minutes;
   ar & seconds;
 }

public:
 int degrees;
 int minutes;
 float seconds;

 gps_position() {};
 gps_position(int d, int m, float s) :
 degrees(d), minutes(m), seconds(s)
 {}
};



int main(int argc, char *argv[])   {
  mpi::environment env(argc, argv);
  mpi::communicator world;

  if(world.rank() == 0) {
    std::vector<gps_position> positions;
    positions.push_back(gps_position(1, 2, 3.));
    positions.push_back(gps_position(5, 6, 10.0));
    std::cout<< "Sent GPS positions:"<<positions.size()<<std::endl;
    world.send(1, 0, positions);
  }
  else {
    std::vector<gps_position> positions;


    world.recv(0, 0, positions);
    std::cout << "Received GPS positions: "<<positions.size() << std::endl;
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<positions.size(); i++) {
      std::cout << positions[i].degrees << "\t"
                << positions[i].minutes << "\t"
                << positions[i].seconds << std::endl;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

However the program is not working properly. looks like the process1 can never receive the vector contain gps_position objects from process0. The output is

```
c:\mpi3>mpiexec -n 2 mpitest 
Sent GPS positions:2 
Received GPS positions: 0
```

I have modified the code to allow it pass single element instead whole vector and it works perfectly. So I have totally no idea about whats wrong with the original code. Is boost::mpi capable to pass this type of vector at all? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you all in advance

Zac

Answer (score 0):

Boost says that it can handle vector...and your type itself it obviously can handle too. naivly i would it expect to work.

check out the following from the boost documentation

> Send data to another process.
>
> This routine executes a potentially blocking send with tag tag to the
>   process with rank dest. It can be received by the destination process
>   with a matching recv call.
>
> The given value must be suitable for transmission over MPI. There are
>   several classes of types that meet these requirements:
>
> ```
> Types with mappings to MPI data types: If is_mpi_datatype<T> is convertible to mpl::true_, then value will be transmitted using the
> ```
>
> MPI data type get_mpi_datatype(). All primitive C++ data types that
>   have MPI equivalents, e.g., int, float, char, double, etc., have
>   built-in mappings to MPI data types. You may turn a Serializable type
>   with fixed structure into an MPI data type by specializing
>   is_mpi_datatype for your type.
>
> ```
> Serializable types: Any type that provides the serialize() functionality required by the Boost.Serialization library can be
> ```
>
> transmitted and received.
>
> ```
> Packed archives and skeletons: Data that has been packed into an mpi::packed_oarchive or the skeletons of data that have been backed
> ```
>
> into an mpi::packed_skeleton_oarchive can be transmitted, but will be
>   received as mpi::packed_iarchive and mpi::packed_skeleton_iarchive,
>   respectively, to allow the values (or skeletons) to be extracted by
>   the destination process.
>
> ```
> Content: Content associated with a previously-transmitted skeleton can be transmitted by send and received by recv. The receiving process
> ```
>
> may only receive content into the content of a value that has been
>   constructed with the matching skeleton.
>
> For types that have mappings to an MPI data type (including the
>   concent of a type), an invocation of this routine will result in a
>   single MPI_Send call. For variable-length data, e.g., serialized types
>   and packed archives, two messages will be sent via MPI_Send: one
>   containing the length of the data and the second containing the data
>   itself. Note that the transmission mode for variable-length data is an
>   implementation detail that is subject to change.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help.

Finally solved this problem by recompile it under VS 2010. Not sure the root reason though. I guess some mismatch in head files and libs?